# Blur Filter in Safari

Tags: css, svg, filter, safari, blur

I'm attempting to blur out a background div, and so far I have a Gaussian blur filter working across chrome, firefox and internet explorer but I was also hoping to have the blur effect show up in Safari and I'm having trouble finding a method that works.

For Internet explorer I'm using:

```
"filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.blur(MakeShadow='false', PixelRadius='3',ShadowOpacity='0.75')"
```

For the basic blur effect. And for Chrome and Firefox I'm using:

```
'filter': 'blur(4px)',
'-webkit-filter': 'blur(4px)',
'-ms-filter': 'blur(4px)',
'background-color': '#000',
'opacity': '0.3',
'filter': 'url("#f1")'
```

Where the last filter is a basic svg blur for firefox. Is there any way I could apply a similar blur style to Safari?

Comment: Which version of safari are you using? CSS3 filter support was only added in version 6. http://caniuse.com/css-filters

Comment: unprefixed CSS should be applyed last, did you try it so ? A codepen.io or jsfiddle.net linked would help you :)